# how you listen for dynamic webhooks with shopify?

Tags: node.js, express, shopify, shopify-app

shopify offers a webhook api for listen to events maybe a product is updated or deleted. I want to build an app where people can connect their shopify store and then I import all products in my database. But I also have to create a webhook for each user that has connected their shop. How can I use dynamic webhooks now ?

I have seen a lot of business that you can connect your shop/multiple shops and you get everytime notifications when a event happend. So its possible but the question is how I create now a webhook for every use that has connected their shop ?

I know how can I create a webhook hardcoded but not dynamically

Comment: When the app is installed it executes a specific function. In that function you create the webhook.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Auth(If you are not using any SDK to process OAuth Flow.) flow function you can implement webhook subscriptions to receive notification of any event.
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/webhook#post-webhooks
Refer this docs you will get better Idea how to create dynamic webhook subscriptions.